# Add relation to a where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many

```rb
Product.where(foo: true).map(&:my_has_one_relation_from_product)
```

I'm not sure if this is possible but I'm looking to have `foo` to return a collection and not an array.

Any way I could do this?

Comment: It is really unclear what you are asking. Can you elaborate? Maybe give a concrete example

Comment: Whatever model you call the `where` on, you're going to a collection of that type. Say the product `has_one :producer`, if you want to get a collection of Producer objects you need to use `Producer.where` and `join`

Answer (score 3):

```
HasOneRelation.joins(:product).where(products: {foo: true})
```

By starting with the has_one_relation you can then join on to products and filter by only the products with `foo: true`. It's a bit of backwards thinking where we are looking for the Relation that has a foo product instead of finding a foo product and grabbing its relation.